# C Segmentation Fault with Modular Programming

Tags: c, malloc, modular

I need to create a program which takes songs and outputs them as a playlist. It's my first time working with malloc and linked lists and I am getting a segmentation fault and I don't know where it is from. I don't think I have overallocated any memory and don't know how to debug or use gdb to solve this issue.

song.h header file

```
#ifndef SONG_H
#define SONG_H
struct song {
    char name[50];
    char artist[50];
    int duration;
    char genre[50];
    struct song* next_song;
    int ID_in_playlist;
};

struct song *getValue (int id);
void Song_New (void);
void Song_Print (void);
void print1song (struct song *ptr);
void CleanUp(struct song *list);
void clean(void);


#endif
```

song.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "song.h"


struct song * firstSong = NULL;
struct song * addedSong = NULL;

struct song *getValue (int id){

    struct song * ptr = NULL;
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct song));
    
    if (ptr != NULL){
        ptr->next_song = NULL;
        ptr->ID_in_playlist = id;

        printf("Type in your song name: ");
        scanf("%s", ptr->name);
        
        printf("Type in your artist name: ");
        scanf("%s", ptr->artist);
        
        printf("Type in your song duration (in seconds): ");
        scanf("%d", &ptr->duration);
        
        printf("Type in your song genre: ");
        scanf("%s", ptr->genre); 
    }
    
    else{
        printf("Allocation Failure!\n");
    }
    
    return ptr;
}

void print1song(struct song *ptr){
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("The value is NULL\n");
    }

    else{
        printf("Name: %s", ptr -> name);
        printf("  Artist: %s", ptr -> artist);
        printf("  Duration: %i", ptr -> duration);
        printf("  Genre: %s", ptr -> genre);
        printf("ID: %d\n", ptr -> ID_in_playlist);
    }
    

    return;
}

void Song_New(){
    int counter = 1;
    if (firstSong == NULL){
        firstSong = getValue(1);
        if (firstSong != NULL){
            addedSong = firstSong;
        }
    }

    else{
        addedSong->next_song = getValue(counter+1);
        if(addedSong->next_song != NULL){
            addedSong = addedSong->next_song;
        }
    }
    printf("Song added successfully!\n");
    counter = counter + 1;

}

void Song_Print (){

    struct song *t;
    t = firstSong;
    if(t == NULL){
        printf("List is empty\n");
    }
    else{
        while(t){
            print1song(t);
            t = t->next_song;
        }
    }
}

void CleanUp(struct song *list){
    struct song *next;
    while(list)
    {
        next = list->next_song;
        free(list);
        list = next;
    }
}

void clean(void){
    CleanUp(firstSong);
    firstSong = NULL;
    addedSong = NULL;

    return;
}
```

main.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "song.h"


int main (void){
    int ans;
    while(1){
        printf("Press 1 to add a new song\n");
        printf("Press 2 to print your songs\n");
        printf("Press 3 to quit\n");
        printf("Input: ");
        scanf("%d", ans);

        if (ans == 1){
            Song_New();
        }

        if (ans == 2){
            Song_Print();
        }

        if (ans == 3){
            printf("Exiting program...");
            break;
        }
    }

    clean();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"don't know how to debug or use gdb"*. Now is a good time to learn then. As a minimum just run your program in gdb and when it crashes get the backtrace with the `bt` command. That will give you the exact line of code that triggers the crash and will be a good place to start looking at the code.

Comment: This is unlikely to be the cause of your crash but do note that `int counter = 1;` is a local variable. It will start back at 1 every time the function is called. So all your songs, except the first one, will have the same id.

Comment: Also, look at and fix all compiler warnings. If you are not getting warnings then read the compiler manual to find out how to turn them on. The compiler should be warning you about this line `scanf("%d", ans);`. That should be `scanf("%d", &ans);` And again, the debugger would almost certainly have instantly pointed you to that line. So it is well worth your time to learn to debug effectively.